# Using "new" operator vs. using "window" object

Tags: javascript

I have a third-party library, which could be envoked through `new` operator:

```
var foo = new bar();
```

It works. Also, I could use `window` object, and it also works:

```
var foo = window.bar();
```

Is there any difference between 1st and 2nd way?

It's OK if this question will be downvoted, but I need some starting point to learn this things.

Comment: Whether or not there is a difference depends on the implementation of that function. I would prefer the first form, as it does not have the chance of accidentally corrupting the `window` object.

Comment: How do you use `foo` afterward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference between 1st and 2nd way?

Yes, they are very different.

#### If `bar` is meant to be used as a constructor

The first way is right, and the second way is wrong.

The first way, `new` creates a new object (using `bar.prototype` as its prototype) and then calls `bar` with `this` set to refer to the new object. `bar` then can populate the object with any instance properties it wants to add:

```
this.something = 42;
```

The second way, you're calling `bar` directly and, because you did that from a property accessor (`window.bar`), `this` when calling `bar` is set to `window`. No new object is created, and the object that `this` refers to (`window`) does not have `bar.prototype` as its prototype. Then if `bar` adds any instance properties, it's **creating global variables** because creating properties on the window object is creating global variables.

So: Use the first. Don't use the second.

#### If `bar` is *not* meant to be used as a constructor

Then they're probably both wrong and you should just be using `bar();`, although `window.bar();` would be okay, just misleading.